# Systemverilog coverpoint for each element in enum

Tags: enums, system-verilog, uvm, bins

I am using UVM environment for verification my design. In monitor, I created coverpoints for my design. However, I can not use  enums for coverpoint bins.

For each coverpoint, I want to create a bin for each element in enum.

For example,
in monitor.sv file

```
enum bit [7:0]
{
   data_type_0 =8'd1,
   data_type_1 =8'd16,
   data_type_2 =8'd32,
   data_type_3 =8'd64
} data_types;

data_type: coverpoint seq_item.data_type
{
  bins data_type_bins[] = {[data_types.first:data_types.last]};
}
```

I tried first and last method, but it creates bin for each number between 1 and 64. I don't want that. I want bins for only 1,16,32,64

Answer (score 0):

I have tried it on 4 simulators and do not get the behaviour you get. So, for example this:

```
    data_type3: coverpoint data_types
    {
    bins data_type_bins[] = {[data_types.first:data_type_2]};
    }
```

gives me 4 bins. However, why not just use:

```
data_type2: coverpoint data_types;
```

and be done with it?

---

```
module M;

  enum bit [7:0]
  {
   data_type_0 =8'd1,
   data_type_1 =8'd16,
   data_type_2 =8'd32,
   data_type_3 =8'd64
  } data_types;

  covergroup CG;
    option.per_instance=1;
    data_type1: coverpoint data_types
    {
    bins data_type_bins[] = {[data_types.first:data_types.last]};
    }
    data_type2: coverpoint data_types;
    data_type3: coverpoint data_types
    {
    bins data_type_bins[] = {[data_types.first:data_type_2]};
    }
  endgroup

  CG cg = new;

  initial
    begin
      data_types = data_type_0;
      cg.sample();
      data_types = data_type_2;
      cg.sample();
      $display("cg.data_type1 covereage = %0f", cg.data_type1.get_coverage());
      $display("cg.data_type2 covereage = %0f", cg.data_type2.get_coverage());
      $display("cg.data_type3 covereage = %0f", cg.data_type3.get_coverage());
    end

endmodule
```

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/a2F

Comment: I am running my simulator in QuestaSim. It gives 64 bin between range. I am not sure it is possible the use "coverpoint data_types" in UVM environment like that. I need to show seq_item.data_type and it refers the hierarchical pin in my design

Comment: @BurakToker Then I think you need a [MCVE] to answer what type is `eq_item.data_type`. A [MCVE] is always better anyway. Not only does it eliminate such confusion, it also saves the person answering the question (me in this case) from having to do the work to create one, which means your question is more likely to receive an answer.